# ajaxForm makes page redirect instead of sending the data back

Tags: php, ajax, ajaxform

Hello I try to upload a picture to my server using ajaxForm.

My problem is that the page is redirecting to the URL in the form action.

This is my ajax code:

```
$("#uploadPicture").html("<form action='actionFilters/TrainerActionFilter.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='pictureUpload'><input type='file' name='picture'/><input type='submit' name='pictureUpload' id='pictureUploadButton' value='Submit' />);

$('#pictureUpload').ajaxForm(function(data)
{

});
```

If I send to the same address normal ajax (not ajaxform) Im not having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but you can try using the `beforeSubmit` function of `ajaxForm`?

```
var ajaxFormOptions = 
{
    beforeSubmit: function() 
    {
        alert("Your action before here");
    }
};  

$('#pictureUpload').ajaxForm(ajaxFormOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the submit in a custom js function then add `onSubmit="return false;"` to the form

```
$("#uploadPicture").html("<form action='actionFilters/TrainerActionFilter.php' onSubmit='return false;' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='pictureUpload'><input type='file' name='picture'/><input type='submit' name='pictureUpload' id='pictureUploadButton' value='Submit' />");

$('#pictureUpload').ajaxForm(function(data)
{

});
```